# InvalidDataContractException in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I am developing an app where i am navigating from different pages Particularly in one page when i am pressing the windows(start) button to come out of the app it is throwing the following exception and Message:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException:
>
> Type 'System.Windows.SetterBase' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.

But i am not getting why this error is occurred. Any suggestions??

Comment: Are you performing any serialization in your application to provide tombstoning support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that when you are naivgating from that page you are either serializing something or saving something in `IsolatedStorageSettings`. This uses the `DataContractSerializer` internally to convert objects into something that can be persisted.

Either make sure that the object can be serialized or serialize it yourself. If you can do it yourself using a different/faster method you may be able to improve performance overall. The `DataContractSerializer` is quite fast with simple types like strings.

Comment: Yes. I am just trying to store my bing map route in app state. when i am coming out of the app this exception is coming... Any suggestions that how to solve this issue. or is there any other way to save the state of the bing map even when the app is deactivated???

Comment: @balaram can you update your question to show the code that you're using to save the data.